# Tomcat 7 'SEVERE: A child container failed during start'

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee, tomcat7

I am developing a web application in Java but while running it I got this problem for tomcat.

```
May 23, 2017 8:47:47 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
    WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Demo' did not find a matching property.
    May 23, 2017 8:47:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.78
    May 23, 2017 8:47:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server built:          May 10 2017 15:02:19 UTC
    May 23, 2017 8:47:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server number:         7.0.78.0
    May 23, 2017 8:47:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: OS Name:               Windows 8.1
    May 23, 2017 8:47:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: OS Version:            6.3
    May 23, 2017 8:47:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Architecture:          amd64
    May 23, 2017 8:47:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
    May 23, 2017 8:47:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JVM Version:           1.7.0_79-b15
    May 23, 2017 8:47:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
    May 23, 2017 8:47:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         G:\Softwares\apache-tomcat-7.0.78
    May 23, 2017 8:47:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         G:\Softwares\apache-tomcat-7.0.78
    May 23, 2017 8:47:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=G:\Softwares\apache-tomcat-7.0.78
    May 23, 2017 8:47:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=G:\Softwares\apache-tomcat-7.0.78
    May 23, 2017 8:47:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=G:\Softwares\apache-tomcat-7.0.78\wtpwebapps
    May 23, 2017 8:47:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=G:\Softwares\apache-tomcat-7.0.78\endorsed
    May 23, 2017 8:47:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
    May 23, 2017 8:47:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
    INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;.;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;.
    May 23, 2017 8:47:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    May 23, 2017 8:47:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    May 23, 2017 8:47:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    INFO: Initialization processed in 690 ms
    May 23, 2017 8:47:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    INFO: Starting service Catalina
    May 23, 2017 8:47:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.78
    May 23, 2017 8:47:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
    SEVERE: A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Demo]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Demo]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name SearchingArtist
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3425)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3404)
        at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.configureContext(WebXml.java:1438)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1359)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:888)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:388)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5522)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        ... 6 more

    May 23, 2017 8:47:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
    SEVERE: A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:444)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:758)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:694)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1127)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        ... 6 more

    May 23, 2017 8:47:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:694)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:758)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        ... 7 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:444)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        ... 9 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1127)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        ... 11 more

    May 23, 2017 8:47:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
    INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    May 23, 2017 8:47:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
    INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    May 23, 2017 8:47:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
    INFO: Stopping service Catalina
    May 23, 2017 8:47:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
    INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    May 23, 2017 8:47:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
    INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

This is the tomcat console.
I tried killing all instances of it like `javaw.exe` and my 8080 port is free still getting this error. What am I suppose to do?

Comment: It looks that the log points to a problem with some SearchingArtist servlet that it cannot map to a class in your application.  Maybe you can share your web.xml if present?

Comment: You have a servlet mapping element for a servlet called SearchingArtist, but there is no matching servlet definition. You cannot create a mapping for a servlet that doesn't exist. Either delete the mapping, or provide a servlet definition for SearchingArtist.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help..solved the problem as the web.xml was not properly written.